# Show Special Characters Name Code

Tags: html, character

I need show `&amp;` (like that) in my page, but when load shows me just '&'. Thats my problem but i really don't know what can i do. And thats all, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to say "`&` as data" instead of "Start of character reference" then use `&amp;`. Then just type of the rest of the characters as they have no special meaning. Therefore:

```
&amp;amp;
```

Comment: i never thought on that... so easy, thank you so much